# убрать отступ при наведении на ссылки?

Tags: css

при наведении на элемент делаю бордер.но начинается дискотека.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как убрать эти танцы диско?

```
li:hover {
  padding: -2px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы делаете padding: -2px;?

Answer (score 2):

Граница влияет на размеры блока. Можно в обычном состоянии задавать прозрачную границу, а при наведении просто менять её цвет, либо использовать `outline`

```css
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

li:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

.without li,
.outline li {
  border: none;
}

.without li:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.outline li:hover {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h5>C предустановленной границей</h5>
<ul>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</ul>
<h5>Без предустановленной границы</h5>
<ul class="without">
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</ul>
<h5> C outline</h5>
<ul class="outline">
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
  <li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</ul>
```